# Should we have a separate tag ("RNP") for Required Navigation Performance questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, on-topic

There is a lot of room for disambiguation when it comes to ICAO RNAV and RNP standards.  This seems to me like RNP should be its own tag separate from RNAV and GNSS tags.

Here are some exemplary tables:
[image]

This one is from the FAA AIM:
[image]

Take a look at all of the "What is this type of RNP?", "What is the difference on this RNP?" type of questions being asked on the site:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We already have a tag for this: [required-nav-performance](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/required-nav-performance). I just added some usage guidance to this tag. Some of the questions you show are already tagged with this.

I would however be in favour of renaming this to [rnp](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rnp) (or at least add a synonym), since this is what people would probably be typing into the tag field when creating a new question. It would also follow the style for the tags [rnav](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rnav) or [gnss](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnss), which use the abbreviation instead of the full form.

---

Status update: completed: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags/rnp/synonyms

Comment: We absolutely need the tag synonym.

Comment: @Lnafziger I agree, but I cannot suggest one: "Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms."

Comment: Actually, a moderator has to do it since [tag:RNP] doesn't already exist.